# consume webservice using dojo

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo

I want to consume a Restful webservice using dojo .
the result of the webservice is returned on the browser but when I tried to get the result using xhr I get always a null value , so please help I'm new in dojo ...

```
dojo.query("li").onclick(function(){
        var xhrArgs = {
                url: "http://192.168.1.65:9080/RAD8JAX-RSWeb/jaxrs/customers",

                handleAs: "json",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                load: function(data) {
                alert("ok");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            };
             dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
 console.log("message sent ...");
});
```

when the event happens the alert displayed and I got "null"

Comment: Are you making the request from an HTML page at on http://192.168.1.65:9080?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo uses 'stores' to fetch data from servers. These stores go out and fetch the data lazily, so only when you first request it. Every time your JavaScript code needs the data it can ask the store and if it has already fetched it, it will return it and otherwise it will go out and fetch it.

Due to the asynchronous nature of the stores you need to do an asynch call every time you need the data.

In your case you could do something like:

```
// Create the store for later use
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
  contentType: 'application/json'
  ,clearOnClose: true
  ,urlPreventCache: true
  ,url: "http://192.168.1.65:9080/RAD8JAX-RSWeb/jaxrs/customers"
});
```

And every time you need to get the data from the store you do:

```
store.fetch({
  onItem: function(item, request) {
    alert('I fire after each returned json item')
  }
  ,onComplete: function(items, findResult) {
    alert('I fire when the data has loaded completely.');
  }
  ,onError: function(error, request) {
    alert('I fire when an error occurs');
  }
});
```

Only the first time there will be a request sent to the server. All other requests will be served from the stores cache. If you want to flush the cache you need to 'close' the store. The next time a fetch will be called on the store will result in a new request to the server.You can close it like so:

```
store.close();
```

Stores are designed to serve server data in a data technique transparant way. So it does not matter it you serve json, xml or csv: it will all be loaded in the store and be served to you in the same way. You just need to know two things:

1. The data needs to be served in a certain format: See http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore#item-structure-examples for the format
2. All items that you get in the onItem and onComplete methods can only be used through the dojo Read API which you can read up on here: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojo/data/api/Read

There are many types of stores, the ItemFileReadStore is just an example.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you very much I really enjoyed your help Ill try this 
I want to show you the json that will be generated when I call the webservice
[{"lastName":"Ziosi","title":"Mr","firstName":"Lara","ssn":"888-88-8888
"}]
how can I handle this , it's a jsonArray :/

Comment: the array is unnamed Is it a problem to use it like that?

Comment: If you read http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore#item-structure-examples you'll see the stores need another json structure. You need to wrap the array in a structure like this:  {
  "identifier": "id",
  "items:[{id: 1. ...other info of this item...},{Id: 2, ...other info of this item...},etc
  ]
}

Comment: while relevant to the question, this is not an answer to the specific problem presented by the questioner.

Comment: What about, let's say we don't have REST full service?

JSON is dynamic and we can't make the changes from the server but still want to filter the data.

How can we achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the dojo.data APIs are a bit more restrictive than the new [dojo.store APIs](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/object-store) (available since 1.6).

For consuming a restful webservice, my advice is to use the [dojo.store.JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) store. No need for a specific Json format.

Here is a nice example of JsonRest usage : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_tree/

Comment: Huh, learn something new every day... Didn't know about the JsonRest store.